# Google Domains and GCP accounts

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-domains

I recently transferred a domain from Yahoo to Google.  I have an environment set up on Google Cloud Platform and (perhaps naïvely) thought I could manage the domain there.  the instructions I found, turns out were for Google Domains (which apparently is a separate system), and I cannot log into GD using the credentials I use for GCP.  So, 2 questions:

1. can I transfer my domain from Google Domains to GCP so I can manage it there?
2. if not, then how do I log into the Admin Console on GD using the same account that I use for GCP?

I've contacted GD tech support and they are completely useless, so I'm hoping someone here can set me straight

TIA

Comment: AFAIK it is not currently possible to transfer a domain _in_ to Cloud Domains. I'd guess this will eventually be added before it goes GA. As for Google Domains, how did you manage to transfer the domain there without being able to log in to it?!

Comment: Yeah man. `domains.google` is where you will find your recently transferred domain. Just log right in with your gmail account. Your gmail account is the owner account for this domain.

Comment: my gmail account is apparent not a "Workspace" account.  so it's odd because the account owns the domain but cannot manage it.  I'm working through it with Support (which leaves much to be desired)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your first question, currently in GCP you can purchase your own domain using Cloud Domains and you can export/migrate it to a different registrar, but it is not possible (at this moment) to import a domain as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/domains/docs/overview#supported_use_cases):

> Note: Cloud Domains does not currently support incoming transfers or
> import of domains. You can make outgoing transfers to Google Domains
> or other registrars directly in Cloud Domains.

Nevertheless, you can delegate the control of your domain to Cloud DNS (or any other DNS provider like GoDaddy) which is also offered in GCP, for that you need to create a new zone in your project for your domain, and you will receive some instructions and nameserver (NS) records. Then you need to replace/update your NS records in your [registrar](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3290309?hl=en) (Google Domains in this case) for those provided by Cloud DNS and wait some time until the propagation is finished, here is the [official guide](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/migrating) about this, but you can find some [useful guides](https://www.cloudbooklet.com/cloud-dns-how-to-transfer-your-domain-to-google-cloud-dns/) on the Internet for your particular use case. This way you can manage your domain from the GCP Console but take into consideration that this is only a delegation, the registrar will still be Google Domains, if by any reason you update your NS records in Google Domains (pointing to a different DNS provider), any change in Cloud DNS will not be effective anymore.

Comment: I just realised you only answered the first question, so I'm re-opening this in hopes of getting an answer to the second question

Comment: For the second question, as it is unrelated to the DNS issue it is better to handle it directly with the Google Domains support team.

Comment: makes sense.  I've reclosed the issue.  thanks for the well thought answer

Comment: You can now import Google Domains into Google Cloud. https://cloud.google.com/domains/docs/import-domains