# Google Domain transfer to Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-domains

I am having an issue with registering a Google Domain as a Google Cloud Domain safely. Even after switching to cloud DNS there is nothing on how to transfer the domain itself to GCD registrar. I've tried googling this but so far no question seemed to be the right one to get my answers.

Comment: Could you share the current status? Any alarm? Warning? Could you describe the steps those you follow until this point?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Domains and GCP accounts](https://serverfault.com/questions/1054197/google-domains-and-gcp-accounts)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, based on the [use cases](https://cloud.google.com/domains/docs/overview#supported_use_cases) of Cloud DNS, you can delegate the control of your domain in GCP but the registrar will maintain in Google Domains, to delegate the control of your domain in GCP configuration are expected from both sides , you can follow the [migrating](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/migrating) procedure, where you have to create in GCP a managed [DNS public zone](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/zones#create-pub-zone) and take note of the NS servers, then, in Google Domains, switch the [DNS configuration](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3290309?hl=en) from Google Domains (Active) to Custom (Active), click on “change to this configuration” and set the NS servers provided by GCP in the public zone created, after that you successfully delegated the control of your domain to Cloud DNS, the next steps are add your [records](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/records) as you needed